# Can't find block

Tags: views, blocks

I have created a view in Drupal 8 that produces a block display. The block does not appear on the block layout page or custom block list.

In the block settings, it identifies the "Block category" as "Lists (Views)"  and claims that this is "The category this block will appear under on the blocks placement page." but it isn't there at all.

I wish I had more detail to include here but this seems really straightforward and I don't know what else to add. It simply isn't there. The preview on the block display in views is fine, everything is saved. I just can't find the block to add it to a region.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on the "Place Block" in the desired region and find it from there. More on block in D8 [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/block/overview).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

View block will show up under "Disabled" section,on clicking "Place Block" we can find  block we created using view and specify the region u want to show it.